# Is it possible to adjust the BLE connection interval on Windows 10?

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a test application up and running using the c# UWP interface to a BLE device but the connection interval is significantly longer than mobile devices attempting the same read process (iPhone 6S has 30ms vs 60ms on Win10).

Is there any way of modifying this as I'd expect a powerful PC to be able to manage a connection interval at the minimum 7.5ms?

Comment: When you test the connection interval again,  can you follow this [guidance](https://github.com/Microsoft/busiotools/tree/master/bluetooth/tracing) to provide your Bluetooth log for us to check?

Comment: The connection interval was confirmed using a BLE sniffer.
My question is whether there's an API to change it?

Comment: Please find zipped log run for: test app open, BLE connection opened, auth / read from device, close app: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vd2hw9n61ownx28/BthTracing.zip?dl=0

Comment: There is no API to change it, we attempt to honor what the device requests, we do recommend a multiple of 7.5ms for scheduling alignment. So some devices use 30ms as an example. Some devices change the value based on scenarios. They use the OTA connection update procedure. And this impacts the battery of the other device as well which is why we honor the devices request where possible.

Comment: You say that you honour what the device requests but at the point of connection (CONNECT_REQ sent out), Interval: 48 (60 msec) is what's sent.

Comment: The interval is a multiple of 7.5ms and some devices may change the value based on scenarios. But there is no API to change it.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the answer to the same question and was able to resolve the issue in the firmware of the device (I've used esp32 with nimble stack).
The device served in this case a role of BLE central. And it seems that the windows tries to accept what device is negotiating, so there is no need to specify this additionally. This was the case for linux implementation as well.
So I ended up doing ble_gap_update_params api call on the embedded side, with connection interval min and max both set to minimum value (it was 0x06), in this manner it was negotiated and confirmed by bluetooth stack running on windows.